# GoogleDrive + Alamofire: Uploading a file with properties

Tags: file-upload, swift2, google-drive-api, alamofire

I am trying to upload a file + parameters to Google Drive via Swift 2/Alamofire.  In the code below, i I change the line that says:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart"
```

to the following:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files"
```

the file uploads to google without a name.  Otherwise, the file upload fails with the same generic code:

```
Error Domain=com.alamofire.error Code=-6003 "Response status code was unacceptable: 400" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Response status code was unacceptable: 400}
```

I'd like to be able to upload the file with name and potentially other parameters as well. I know I'm mangling the multipart upload somehow, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
  func postBinaryToGdriveSimple (token: String, callback: Bool -> Void){
var returnedId : String!
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("drawing", ofType: "bin")

let bindata: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path!))!
let parameters : [String: String] = ["title":"SomeFileName"]
let headers = ["Authorization": "Bearer \(token)"]
upload(
  .POST,
  "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
  headers: headers,

  multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    // append file parameters to request
    for (key, value) in parameters {
      multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: value.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!, name: key)
    }
    // append binary file to request
    multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: bindata, name: "upload", fileName: "drawing.bin", mimeType: "application/octet-stream")

  },
  encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
    switch encodingResult {
    case .Success(let upload, _, _):
      upload.progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
          let percent = (Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite))
          //progress(percent: percent)
          print ("................\(percent)")
        }
      }
      upload.validate()
      upload.responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .Success(let data):
          print(response)
          print("Validation Successful")

          let json = JSON(data)
          returnedId = json[("id")].stringValue
          print("......id for uploaded file is \(returnedId)")

          callback(true)
        case .Failure(let error):
          print(error)
          print("Validation Bad")
          callback(false)
        }


      }
    case .Failure(_):
      callback(false)
    }
})
} // end of postBinaryToGdriveSimple
```

I wonder if there is something about the way Alamofire creates the multipart request that Google Drive is not liking.  From the google api site, it seems like a request needs to have certain parameters that Alamofire may not be creating, such as Content-length and boundary settings...

```
POST /upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer your_auth_token
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=foo_bar_baz
Content-Length: number_of_bytes_in_entire_request_body

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
 "name": "My File"
}

--foo_bar_baz
Content-Type: image/jpeg

JPEG data
--foo_bar_baz--
```

If so, what is the work-around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double check the API documentation for Google Drive.

It appears that the key field for the parameter is "name" (not "title").

If you want additional, custom file properties, restricted to the single app, add an "appProperties" to the json:

"appProperties": {
  "title": "whatever"
}

Comment: Many thanks for taking a look at my issue.  You are correct about my oversight regarding the "name" parameter...However, that has not solved the issue.  I updated my question to include a blurb about multipart requests from the GoogleDrive API docs...Is it possible that Alamofire is not sending all the info necessary to make the request? If so, how to fix?

Comment: oh ok, try commenting out the for in loop inside the multipartFormData closure and see what happens if you add:  multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"{'name':'FILE_NAME'}".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"name", mimeType: "application/json")

Comment: btw, the boundaries are set by alamofire, when you 'append a body part'. AF method should be self extracting the Content-Length for the POST, and the mimeType param sets the Content-Type for that part of the request. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/MultipartFormData.swift

Comment: Brilliant!  once again, you've come through.  I love the simplicity of this answer.  multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"{'name':'FILE_NAME'}".dataUsingEncoding(N‌​SUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"name", mimeType: "application/json")  solved my problem.  Much appreciated!

Comment: Cool.  So just to add some color... whatever is added inside the main quotes of the multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data:"DATA_TO_ENCODE" argument is encoded.  Note that those main quotes define a string in Swift and are not included in the encoding, just like your parameters dictionary variable.  JSON needs the {}, :  and the "" characters.  I'm using single quotes for ease in answering, but the JSON standard is double quotes so technically you should use \" (the escape double quote where I have the ' single quote character).  Then you set the Content-Type to application/json via mimeType.